# Как заново сериализовать объект

Tags: java, сокет, сериализация, io, serializable

Вот небольшой пример кода, сильно упрощённый:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Part of project: SerializationTest.
 * Created by Maksim on 19.03.2017.
*/
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 1) {
            try(Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9876);
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
                Test test = (Test) objectInputStream.readObject();
                System.out.println(test.getA());
                test = (Test) objectInputStream.readObject();
                System.out.println(test.getA());
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9876);
                 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                 ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                Test test = new Test(10);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(test);
                objectOutputStream.flush();

                test.setA(110);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(test);
                objectOutputStream.flush();
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Это клиент-сервер. Вот сам класс Test:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Part of project: SerializationTest.
 * Created by Maksim on 19.03.2017.
 */
public class Test implements Serializable{
    private int a;

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

10

10

Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось:

10

110

Мне надо это для экономии памяти, чтобы использовать один класс обёртку для передачи данных. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [reset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()) класса `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
test.setA(110);
objectOutputStream.reset();
objectOutputStream.writeObject(test);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. А не подскажите как происходит проверка наличия такого же объекта, по hash-у или просто если объект с такой ссылкой уже есть в кэше то он и отправляется?

Comment: @МаксимДробышев на здоровье. Судя по коду `ObjectOutputStream`, по ссылке. Изменение hashcode не помогает - в этом можно убедиться и на этом примере.